# Fractional part of epoch

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I have an epoch value of 1372252864.901871 which needs to be converted to localtime in perl. I know that localtime($val) where $val is set to   1372252864.901871 converts the value to local time. But I also need to add values of 100 msecs or say 86.7 msecs to this and determine the computed local time. How do I do this? Does the function localtime() take care of fractional epoch value that I have given?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to add to an epoch time and get another epoch time, just do:

```
1372252864.901871 + .0867
```

If you are doing something else, no, localtime does not preserve fractional seconds.  You probably want to use DateTime to deal with fractional seconds:

```
use DateTime;
my $time = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch=>1372252864.901871, time_zone=>'local');
$time->add(nanoseconds=>86.7e6);
print $time->epoch + $time->nanosecond / 1e9;
```

(time_zone isn't needed for this example, but sounds like what you might want for other things you might be doing with this time)

Answer (score 0):

You might want [Time::HiRes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes):

> The Time::HiRes module implements a Perl interface to the usleep,
>   nanosleep, ualarm, gettimeofday, and setitimer/getitimer system calls,
>   in other words, high resolution time and timers

Comment: I don't think `Time::HiRes` addresses the OP's requirements. He already has a high-resolution time value `1372252864.901871`. He wants to break it down into year, month, ..., seconds, with the seconds in high resolution.

Comment: Exactly. Time::HiRes doesn't work out for me. I need to convert the epoch to Year-Month-Day-Secs-Millisecs resolution. I then need to add values of x msecs to this. Are there any functions which take care of addition of values to local time?

Comment: I think you might be over-complicating the problem. Since an epoch date is in seconds, and the hi-res value is in fractional seconds, turn x msec into x fractional seconds by dividing my 1000. Add it to your existing fractional seconds and Bob's your uncle?

Comment: In other words - keep the time in fractional epoch form - don't convert to a localtime list until you need to use it for display.

Comment: Do you just need the epoch value converted to date/time fields, or do you want correction for the current time zone? Also, you say you want *Year-Month-Day-Secs-Millisecs*. Not hours and minutes?

Answer (score 0):

The `localtime` function breaks down a raw time like `1372252864` into year, month, day, etc. Any fractional part of the raw time is quietly ignored.

I'm not aware of any function, either built-in or in a module, that supports broken-down times with a resolution finer than 1 second.

But since you *already have* the fractional seconds, I'd say you can already do what you need to do. Just use `localtime` (or `gmtime`) to break down the integer part of your raw timestamp, and then take the fractional part:

```
$timestamp = 1372252864.901871;
@parts = localtime($timestamp);
$fraction = $timestamp - int($timestamp);
$milliseconds = int($fraction * 1000.0);
```

It should be easy enough to write your own high-resolution replacement for `localtime` that does this for you.

If you need to add 86.7 milliseconds to a timestamp, you'll need to use the raw form anyway:

```
$timestamp = 1372252864.901871;
$timestamp += 86.7/1000.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that occurs to me is to use [`Time::HiRes::Value`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes::Value) to handle arithmetic on times to 1μs accuracy, and [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) to format the result as a date/time string.

`Time::HiRes::Value` holds the time as a two-element array; the first field has the whole seconds while the second has the number of microseconds. That's the same format that `Time::HiRes` functions work with, but there's nothing that I know of that will natively convert to a date/time string so I've used `Time::Piece` to convert the whole seconds and just appended the fractional seconds.

It looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes::Value;
use Time::Piece;

my $dt    = Time::HiRes::Value->new(1372252864.901871);
my $delta = Time::HiRes::Value->new(86.7E-3); # 86.7ms
$dt += $delta;
print dt_to_string($dt), "\n";

sub dt_to_string {
  my ($dt) = @_;
  Time::Piece->new($dt->[0])->datetime =~ s{(\d+)\z}{$1 + $dt->[1] / 1E6}er;
}
```

**output**

```
2013-06-26T14:21:4.98857
```